# Why Scala `var` is highlighted red in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

Does anyone know if the subj is expected or IDE is trying to warn me about something?

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

My Eclipse is 
Mars Release (4.5.0)
Scala IDE for Eclipse   4.3.0.v-2_11-201512011536-499c89a

Comment: Scala favors immutable `val` over `var`. Vars are highlighted in red, just to make you aware that you are using mutable state. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for **Syntax Coloring** inside of Preferences window in Eclipse.

Example for Java:

[image]

Comment: That's right, `Semantic` -> `Local var` indeed has Foreground color set to red. Thanks!